pytorch with CUDA
Я сталкиваюсь с проблемами при установке и использовании PyTorch с поддержкой CUDA на моем компьютере. Вот некоторые данные о системе и шаги, которые я предпринял:
Данные о системе:

Видеокарта: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
Версия драйвера NVIDIA: 566.03
Версия CUDA (по данным nvidia-smi): 12.7
Версия CUDA (по данным nvcc): 11.7

Шаги, которые я предпринял:

Установил Anaconda и создал окружение pytorch_env.
Установил PyTorch, torchvision и torchaudio с помощью команды:
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia


Проверил установку, запустив Python и выполнив следующие команды:
import torch
print(torch.__version__)           # Версия PyTorch: 2.4.1
print(torch.cuda.is_available())   # Доступность CUDA: False



Проблема:
Несмотря на то что PyTorch установлен, доступность CUDA возвращает False. Я проверил драйвера NVIDIA и установку CUDA Toolkit, но проблема остается.
Вопрос:

Как мне правильно настроить PyTorch для работы с CUDA?
Нужно ли устанавливать другую версию PyTorch или драйвера NVIDIA для решения этой проблемы?
Есть ли дополнительные шаги, которые я мог бы предпринять для устранения этой проблемы?

Буду благодарен за любую помощь или советы!

Попробуйте слегка поменять строку инсталляции, добавив -gpu: conda install pytorch-gpu, остаток строки без изменения. Если не поможет, попробуйте удалить pytorch из conda и ещё раз установить той же самой командой, что и раньше, некоторым помогло.

спасибо , попробую
